# Titanium Appcelerator accessing ListView data-binded label text?

Tags: android, listview, data-binding, titanium, appcelerator

It is giving me an undefinied error of the Label with the id="somethinggooood"
But if I create the Label outside the ListView it can access it with no problem

Is there any workaround this or any other way to fix it?

Alloy.XML

```
<ListView id="userList" 
          defaultItemTemplate="user"             
          onItemclick="userProfile" >

        <Templates >

            <ItemTemplate bindId="user" name="user" >
                <View backgroundColor="red" layout="vertical">
                    <Label bindId="name"  />
                    <Label bindId="title" id="somethinggooood" /> 
                    //THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO ACCESS
                    <ImageView id="goodb" bindId="img" />   
                </View>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </Templates>

        <ListSection id="section" dataCollection="users" >
            <ListItem template="user" 
                      user:id="{id}" 
                      img:image="{author_img}" 
                      name:text="{adresse}" 
                      title:text="{title}" />

        </ListSection>



</ListView>
```

JS

```
function goodfff(){
   alert($.somethinggooood.text);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Any item inside the listview is not accessible by ID because of the way it is loaded in. You can get the data back from the ListView by getting the row itself and then you'll get the data that you used to set the view.

Changing it on-the-fly like that isn't possible either, you'll need to re-create the item and update the item with the new data.

Comment: ListItem you mean(which i didnt have any luck with either), or how could I access the `ListView Row`?

Comment: I only care about accessing them, to list all of them in an alert box or something, i dont want to change them